# from_unixtime thinks data is string where data is int/bigint in hadoop hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My code is as below..

```
SELECT
        to_date(from_unixtime(time_first_touch)) AS sDate
    FROM (
SELECT
            MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time')) as time_first_touch,
            COUNT(*) as number_of_events
        FROM swanviraw
    ) v
```

Its throwing an error- Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 2:10 Wrong arguments 'time_first_touch': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(bigint) *FUNC*(bigint, string) *FUNC*(int) *FUNC*(int, string) [ERROR_STATUS]

Now, the point is the following query is working fine.. the ev_time has int/bigint values as MIN works perfectly in the following..

```
 SELECT
                    MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time')) as time_first_touch,
                    COUNT(*) as number_of_events
                FROM swanviraw
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: `MIN(unix_timestamp(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time')))` - have you tried this?

Comment: ev_time is unixtime, why to convert it again..

Comment: because `GET_JSON_OBJECT` returns json string...so `MIN(unix_timestamp(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time')))` OR `MIN(cast(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time') ` should work  - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object

Comment: MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time')) is working.. the problem is happening in from_unixtime..

Comment: `MIN(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time'))` is returning `string` data type - you need to `cast` expected datatype by `from_unixtime()` which is `int or bigint`

Comment: ok.. I will try casting inside from_unixtime parameter

Comment: why not `cast` to `bigint` first than get `MIN`? wouldn't be that accurate of getting `MIN` of `bigint`  than getting `MIN` of `string`?

Comment: I will try that as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `GET_JSON_OBJECT` [returns json string](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object), and as error indicates that `from_unixtime` expect `int` or `bigint`, you need to convert `time_first_touch` to `bigint`:

```
SELECT
        to_date(from_unixtime(time_first_touch)) AS sDate
    FROM (
SELECT
            MIN(cast(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time') as bigint)) as time_first_touch,
            COUNT(*) as number_of_events
        FROM swanviraw
    ) as v
```

OR

```
SELECT
        to_date(from_unixtime(time_first_touch)) AS sDate
    FROM (
SELECT
            MIN(unix_timestamp(GET_JSON_OBJECT(swanviraw.textcol,'$.ev_time'))) as time_first_touch,
            COUNT(*) as number_of_events
        FROM swanviraw
    ) as v
```